# Add element without namespace in smack message

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack

I wants to add node element in smack Message .

Eg. `<myID>`  is the custom tag which i wants to add in message. like below structure

```
<message to='username@domain' id='12345'><body>Hello</body><myID>33e6cf03-90aa-4281-a36e-902ccdf0657f</myID></message>
```

What i tried so far By creating `CustomExtension` by implementing [`DefaultExtensionElement`](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/4.1.0/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/DefaultExtensionElement.html)   but here its creating message with some namespace specified.

```
<message to='username@domain' id='12345'><body>Hello</body><myID xmlns='somenamespace'>33e6cf03-90aa-4281-a36e-902ccdf0657f</myID></message>
```

But i wants to add **without** namespace as a element.

Any help ?

*I checked already asked and answered questions but all are with namespace.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP expects you to qualify custom extensions with a namespace. That's why Smack doesn't make it easy to work around that requirement.